# how long does it take to write a PCIE to Serial windows driver with zero knowledge?

Tags: windows, serial-port, driver, pci-e, kmdf

I need to write a serial driver for PCIE with interrupts, contigious buffer DMA and simple read/write requests from PC to PCIE. I have no knowledge on drivers and small knowledge on PC architecture. How long should it take on average?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the weather, I'd say somewhere between 2 hours and 9 months.

Comment: I guiltily hope this gets a reversal badge.